# Custom SurfaceView: draws not appears

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am using custom surfaceview. But draws not appears and view is full black:

```
public class SV extends SurfaceView {

    Context context;

    public SV (Context a_context)
    {
        super(a_context);
        context = a_context;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw (Canvas c)
    {
        c.drawColor(0xFFFF0000);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        c.drawCircle(c.getWidth()/2, c.getHeight()/2, 150, p);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw (Canvas c)
    {
        c.drawColor(0xFF0088FF);
    }

}
```

and in onCreate activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SV sv = new SV (this);
    setContentView(sv);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `setWillNotDraw(false)` to the statement into the `surfaceCreated()` method which is from `SurfaceHolder.Callback`. So you need to add the following code in your `Activity`.

```
public class CameraPreview extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private SurfaceHolder holder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // your activity initiating code
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // Do somthing when surface changed.
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
       // Do something when surface first created.
       // add setWillNotDraw(false) to enable onDraw() and other functions
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
       // cleanup here
    }


}
```